Problem in building ROS2 on Windows 10 (vcs install related issue)
I am referring to ROS2 Iron Beginner client libraries tutorial documents to learn it on Windows 10.
I gave the code colcon build --symlink-install --merge-install in cmd to build the workspace and received an error saying
0 packages finished, 12 packages aborted, 12 packages had stderr output

So I referred to the 'alternative' section in the installation documentation to build ROS2. Which uses the command:
vcs import --input https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros2/ros2/iron/ros2.repos src

to get the repositories. Then I got the error saying
vcs is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

So I tried to install vcs using pip install vcs. Which gave me the below error:
C:\iron>pip install vcs
Collecting vcs
  Using cached vcs-0.4.0.tar.gz (482 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [19 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\resea\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qt6ojzuu\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "C:\Users\resea\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qt6ojzuu\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\resea\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qt6ojzuu\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\resea\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-qt6ojzuu\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 11
          except IOError, err:
                        ^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.


I don't know how to proceed with this. I cannot build ROS2 by getting Github repositories as vcs is not getting installed.
Note: I have to use VS2022 even though installation documents say to use VS2019, as community no longer offers VS2019. Is it somehow contributing to the above error?

Could you try to run pip install vcstool instead like being mentioned here
https://answers.ros.org/question/386163/vcs-command-not-found/

Hello Michael, Thank you for your reply. I tried this. vcstools installation is  successful. However when I give the command to import from github (vcs import....) it still gives me the same error. However, I checked my C disk and now I see some files that have been created from my previous tries. That means it had done what it should do. But, still I get errors when I proceed with the tutorial. Clueless but trying to figure out the issue.

I fixed the command above. It incorrectly called out vcstools which is a different package that vcstool not that it's not plural.
